# Reading the name of the father of Johann Henrich Illart (Mihla, 1731)

Tags: germany, palaeography, church-records, thuringia

I cannot read the name of Johann Henrich Illart's father from either his baptism nor his burial record.  It looks like "S__ndal" to my eye, and if I'm reading it right, it shows him as being a "Ackerknecht" (farmhand) from Mihla.  I have recorded the names and family tree of every Illart/Illert who should have been alive in Mihla at the time, but cannot match that pattern to any name.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first name you are looking for is *Wendel*. You can find each letter elsewhere: *W* in *Wilhelm* (at the top), *e* and *n* for example in *begraben* (right next to the name), *d* and *l* in Kindlein (line below).

The last name though is almost certainly Iffart, not Illart, so probably not related to the Illerts you have recently been looking at. Your reading of *Ackerknecht* as the occupation is correct.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right on the ff, as well.  I noticed another Iffart pop up in the area a couple of decades later.  I'm still planning to keep an eye for Iffarts though,  until I'm sure it wasn't just a case of the priest spelling "ll" as the similarly sounding "ff", rather than an actual separate last name.